# Lucene Porter Stemmer - get original unstemmed word

Tags: lucene, stemming

I have worked out how to use Lucene's Porter Stemmer but would like to also retrieve the original, un-stemmed word. So, to this end, I added a CharTermAttribute to the TokenStream before creating the PorterStemFilter, as follows:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
TokenStream original = analyzer.tokenStream("StandardTokenStream", new StringReader(inputText));
TokenStream stemmed = new PorterStemFilter(original);
CharTermAttribute originalWordAttribute = original.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
CharTermAttribute stemmedWordAttribute = stemmed.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

stemmed.reset();
while (stemmed.incrementToken()) {
    System.out.println(stemmedWordAttribute+" "+originalWordAttribute);
}
```

Unfortunately, both attributes return the stemmed word.
Is there a way to get the original word as well?

Answer (score 1):

Lucene's [PorterStemFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_11_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/PorterStemFilter.html) can be combined with Lucene's [KeywordRepeatFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_11_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/KeywordRepeatFilter.html). The Porter Stemmer uses this to provide both the stemmed and unstemmed tokens.

Modifying your approach:

```java
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
TokenStream original = analyzer.tokenStream("StandardTokenStream", new StringReader(inputText));
TokenStream repeated = new KeywordRepeatFilter(original);
TokenStream stemmed = new PorterStemFilter(repeated);
CharTermAttribute stemmedWordAttribute = stemmed.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

stemmed.reset();
while (stemmed.incrementToken()) {
    String originalWord = stemmedWordAttribute.toString();
    stemmed.incrementToken();
    String stemmedWord = stemmedWordAttribute.toString();
    System.out.println(originalWord + " " + stemmedWord);
}
```

This is fairly crude, but shows the approach.

Example input:

```
testing giraffe book passing
```

Resulting output:

```
testing test
giraffe giraff
book book
passing pass
```

For each pair of tokens, if the second matches the first (`book book`), then there was no stemming.

---

Normally, you would use this with `RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilter` to remove the duplicate `book` term - but if you do that I think it becomes much harder to track the stemmed/unstemmed pairs - so for your specific scenario, I did not use that de-duplication filter.